# why doesn't load any pictures, styles or scripts of site in iss?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, roles

I use IIS for viewing my site. when I browse it, it shows just text, and doesn't load any pictures, styles or scripts. 
when I use firebuge to view css , it shows this messegae:

> This element has no style rules. You can create a rule for it.

what should I do?

Comment: The links to the files are probably wrong. Check the Net tab in Firebug, it will probably show a 404 error for all these files.

Comment: @ZippyV no, i dont have that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By turning on  **"Static Content"**, my problem solved.
 "Static Content" is in this path:

> Control panel --> programs and features --> Turn windows features on
>   or off --> Internet Information Services --> world wide web services
>   --> Common HTTP features

thanks all...

Answer (score 0):

I think ZippyV is right. You are referencing the .css wrong; double and triple check.
Check how everything is mapped on your IIS to be sure.